# Errors in Rstudio loading and installing packages (ANN2 and other Neural Network Packages)

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I have had issues in the past week with attempting to download packages into my R studio. Specifically, ANN2, caret, and mxnet. When using the install.packages("name of package"), I get an error indicating certain dependencies (such as ggplot2) are not installed, when in reality they have been successfully. After attempting to reinstall those packages I was presented with this error:

```
> library("ANN2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
```

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Matt/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

There has been similar issues on his site, with none of them presenting a solution that worked.

The problem became worse this morning as when I opened the Rstudio window a pop-up from Rstudio appeared saying "The procedure entry point DATAPTR could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\the location information within the computer". As suggested by an answer to a similar question, I restarted my computer and reinstalled Rstudio. The problem has still persisted after these fixes. To make matters worse I have now lost a handful of other packages that were successfully installed previously (such as NeuralNetTools and ggplot2) due to this problem.

Here are a list of things I have tried and did not succeed.

- Updating Rstudio to the most current version and booting old version
- Reinstalling Rstudio
- Manually installing the packages using their zip files
- Installing the packages from commands in the console
- Installing the packages from the library tab
  These all present the aforementioned error, or a series of errors that leads back to this error after installing the dependent packages.

These issues may not be truly related, but they present similar symptoms with a hopefully simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by completely uninstalling Rstudio and also deleting all of the documents and files containing any trace of R from my computer. Once that was done, I was able to reinstall R from scratch and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that the above mentioned error messages occure, when using R and packages that are not homogenous in terms of their built, e.g. using R 3.4 on packages of built 3.5 or the other way round...

Check if your R Version and the used packages are homogenous in terms of their built and re-install packages with the R version used to re-compile them to the homogenous built needed...this may solve the mentioned issue above...